# Coffeescript function with options

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have a webpage where I want to show different graphs with Kendoui Dataviz graphs.
These graphs have different options. Now I want to be able to set the correct graph options from HTML. Not like the Kendoui docs, where the options are always bound to a certain #id. Not very dynamic. So I start with the HTML like this:

```
<div data-options="CheapOptions" class="chartholder">
    <div id="Cheapo" style="height:180px;width:500px" class="chartClass"></div>
</div>
<div data-options="ExpensiveOptions" class="chartholder">
    <div id="Expensive" style="height:180px;width:500px" class="chartClass"></div>
</div>
```

And then I have a Coffeescript (auto compiling to JS, without the function wrapper) where I set the options and run a function that decides which divs should display which graph.

```
CheapOptions =
    series: [
            name: "Costs 1"
            data: [100]
    ,
            name: "Costs 2"
            data: [200]
    ]

ExpensiveOptions =
    series: [
            name: "Costs 1"
            data: [300]
            color: "#AABBCC"
    ,
            name: "Costs 2"
            data: [400]
    ]

$ ->
    $(".chartholder").each ->
            mydiv = $(this)
            myoptions =  mydiv.data("options")
            mygraph =  mydiv.children(":first")
            myid = "#" + mygraph.attr("id")

            # APPLY THE GRAPH
            $(myid).kendoChart myoptions      # DOESN'T WORK
            $(myid).kendoChart[myoptions]()   # DOESN'T WORK
            $(myid).kendoChart CheapOptions   # WORKS
```

The first option gives this error:

```
Error: Cannot call method 'CheapOptions' of kendoChart before it is initialized
```

The second option gives this error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$(n).kendoChart[r]()')
```

The third option works to show that the function can see the options, but then I get the same graph in all divs, while it should use the correct one that I put in the HTML. How can I do this?

Here's a JSFiddle where you can play with the options:
http://jsfiddle.net/5TFAk/5/

Comment: Solved it using eval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better approach (eval is dangerous and should be avoided):

```
options =
  CheapOptions:
    series: [
        name: "Costs 1"
        data: [100]
    ,
        name: "Costs 2"
        data: [200]
    ]
  ExpensiveOptions:
    series: [
        name: "Costs 1"
        data: [300]
        color: "#AABBCC"
    ,
        name: "Costs 2"
        data: [400]
    ]
```

and then:

```
$(myid).kendoChart options[myoptions]
```